# Something that should seem simple

Tags: bash, scripts, vim

As mentioned in the title, this should be something simple, but for the life of me I can't get it to work right.

I am writing a small executable script that will take care of entering the ever-so-needed interpreter location for the first line of a script and opening the new script for editing. Alright, cool...done: `printf "#!%s" $(which bash) > $1; vim $1`. Simple enough.

Where the problem, only perceived as a problem because I am curious as to how to do it and am not achieving it, is having the script automatically start me off on line 2 in insert mode. This way I am on an empty line, ready to go...without wasting the .5 seconds or so to press 'o' (I am using vim as my text editor for reference).

So I guess my question is how do I get my automated script to simulate pressing 'o' when the newly created script opens up with the output of '#!`$(which bash)`' on the first line?

Things tried:

- Using newline character escaped with printf: `printf "#!%s\n" $(which bash) > $1`
- Using echo with newline character flag: `echo -e "#!$(which bash)\n" > $1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
printf '#!%s\n\n' $(which bash) > "$1" ; vim -c startinsert +2 "$1"
```

It inserts two newlines to the file, so no <kbd>o</kbd> is needed. It then starts vim on the second line (+2) in the insert mode.

Also, prefer single quotes to double quotes if no expansion is needed. In this case, `!` might get interpreted as the history expansion special character in double quotes and totally change what is printed.

Comment: Always nice to see multiple ways of doing the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

The things you tried are not going to help, since this does not depend on the file's contents; rather, it depends on the text editor.

In Vim, the following should work:

```
vim "$file" +'$normal o' +'startinsert'
```

Each `+` argument is interpreted in "command mode"; usually it's the line number but any command actually works. `:$normal o` appends an empty line after the last line (it's ugly but I couldn't think of any other way); `:startinsert` enters the insert mode.

Comment: Perfect, I completely forgot about vim having it's own command processor and I subconsciously knew that's what I was looking for. The dots weren't connecting though. Thanks, worked like a charm!

Comment: How about `vim $'+i\n#!/usr/bin/env bash\n\n.\n' +startinsert "$1"`?